# Circular UIImageView is square on some devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a `UIView` that has a `UIImageView` in it.

I set the `UIImageView` to be circular and add a border to it like this:

```
self.profilePicImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profilePicImageView.frame.size.height / 2
self.profilePicImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

self.profilePicImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
self.profilePicImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3
```

It's being called after I initialize the view in my `viewController` and before I add it as a subview (function called `setupUI()`).

It works perfectly fine on most of the devices, but on the large screen devices (iPhone 6/6s/7 Plus and iPhone X) I get the border right but the image itself isn't circular.

**Please see the examples:**

Regular iPhones:

[image: Regular]

Large iPhones (iPhone 6/6s/7 Plus and iPhone X):

[image: Large]

Any idea what the problem can be and how can I fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: @FS.06  I'hd also face this issues, so add following line your code  
self.profilePicImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
self.profilePicImageView.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @FS.O6 please try my edited answer, it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code it will help you.

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageHeight/2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```